# Determining Littlewood-Richardson coefficients $c_{\lambda,\mu}^{(2)}$ and $c_{\lambda,\mu}^{(1,1)}$.

Tags: combinatorics, representation-theory, symmetric-polynomials, symmetric-functions

We denote the Littlewood-Richardson coefficient by $c_{\lambda, \mu}^{\nu}$ where $\mu$ is a partition of $m$ and $\nu$ is a partition of $n$ and $\lambda$ is a partition of $m+n$. We know $c_{\lambda, \mu}^{\nu}=\langle s_{\lambda}, s_{\eta}s_{\mu}\rangle$ where $s_{\lambda}$ is the Schur function corresponding to the partition $\lambda$. My question is about the determination of the numbers $c_{\lambda, \mu}^{(2)}$ and $c_{\lambda,\mu}^{(1,1)}$ where $\lambda$ is a partition of $n$ and $\mu$ is a partition of $n-2$. I get the following answer.

$$c_{\lambda,\mu}^{(2)}=\begin{cases} 1 & \text{when $\lambda$ can be obtained from $\mu$ by adding two boxes to the rows of the Young diagram of $\mu$} \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}.\end{cases}$$

Similarly, $$c_{\lambda,\mu}^{(1,1)}=\begin{cases} 1 & \text{when $\lambda$ can be obtained from $\mu$ by adding two boxes, but not in the same row, to the Young diagram of $\mu$} \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}.\end{cases}$$

Let us take an example to demonstrate this. We assume $\lambda=(4,2,2)\vdash 8$. We remove two boxes from the Young diagram of $\lambda$ such that it remains a Young diagram. The partitions of six that we get after doing that are $\{(2,2,2),(4,2),(4,1,1), (3,2,1)\}.$ Clearly these are all partitions of six such that if we add add two boxes to their Young diagram we get back $\lambda$. Thus,
$$c_{(4,2,2),\mu}^{(2)}=\begin{cases} 1 & \text{when $\mu\in\{(2,2,2),(4,2),(4,1,1), (3,2,1)$\}} \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}.\end{cases}$$
By similar consideration, we get
$$c_{(4,2,2),\mu}^{(1,1)}=\begin{cases} 1 & \text{when $\mu\in\{(4,1,1), (3,2,1)$\}} \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}.\end{cases}$$

Now the problem is that I found the following in a certain reference without any explanation.

$$c_{\lambda,\mu}^{(2)}=\begin{cases} 1 & \text{when $\lambda$ can be obtained from $\mu$ by adding two boxes to the columns, but not in the same column, in the Young diagram of $\mu$} \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}.\end{cases}$$

Considering this description we see that,

$$c_{(4,2,2),\mu}^{(2)}=\begin{cases} 1 & \text{when $\mu\in\{(2,2,2),(4,2),(3,2,1)$\}} \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}.\end{cases}$$

I don't understand where I am going wrong. The proof of my deduction is as follows:

We have,
$$s_{\mu}s_{(1,1)}=\sum_{\lambda\vdash n}c_{\lambda,\mu}^{(1,1)}s_{\lambda}.$$ The coefficient $c_{\lambda,\mu}^{(1,1)}$ is the coefficient of $x^{\lambda+\delta}$ in $a_{\delta}s_{\mu}s_{(1,1)}$. But since $s_{\mu}=\frac{a_{\mu+\delta}}{a_{\delta}}$, we have to find the coefficient of $x^{\lambda+\delta}$ in $a_{\mu+\delta}s_{(1,1)}$. Note that $\delta=(n-1,\cdots,1,0)$ and $a_{\delta}$ is the Van-der-Monde determinant corresponding $\delta$.

Note that $s_{(1,1)}$ is just the elementary symmetric function $e_{2}=m_{(1,1)}$ where $m_{\eta}$ is the monomial symmetric function corresponding to a partition $\eta$. Thus we have to find the coefficient of $x^{\lambda+\delta}$ in $a_{\mu+\delta}e_{2}$. Since $a_{\mu +\delta}$ is a alternating polynomial, thus it's coefficient is determined by $x^{\mu+\delta}$ which is one. Thus the coefficient of $x_{\lambda+\delta}$ is $a_{\mu+\delta}e_2$ is one when $\lambda$ can be obtained from $\mu$ by adding one box each to two different rows of the Young diagram of $\mu$, zero otherwise.

The proof of $c_{\lambda,\mu}^{(2)}$ goes similarly by observing that $s_{(2)}=h_2$ where $h_2$ is the complete symmetric function corresponding to 2, that is, $h_2=m_2+m_{(1,1)}$. Note that because of the presence of $m_2$ we now get rid of the condition that two boxes are to be added in different rows.

Note that the above proof is based on the proof of Pieri's rule. Thank you in advance for any kind of assistance.

Comment: Your description of $c^{(2)}_{\lambda\mu}$ is wrong, I think. There are indeed exactly five characters of the restriction of $\chi_{(4,2,2)}$ to $S_6\times S_2$, three of which are trivial for the second factor.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven I agree to what you are saying. I also checked the same. Therefore the reference is saying the correct thing! But I believe that the description is not wrong. Probably there is something wrong with the proof. Can you elaborate a little? Do you think the computation for $c_{\lambda,\mu}^{(1,1)}$ is also wrong although it checks out correctly for the example that I choose, since they are two irreducible representations of $S_6\times S_2$ in the restriction map, with the second factor being the sign representation for $S_2$.

Comment: Okay I now understand what you mean, when you say that the description is wrong! So basically the description I found from the reference is the correct one. Buy yeah I also have a proof for my description which is somewhere not correct. I don't see it though!

Comment: What should be the description in terms of rows then? The description given in the reference is in terms of columns for which I have no idea how to prove! Yes of course one can work with the conjugate transpose of $\mu$ and $\lambda$ to get a description in terms of columns of $\lambda$ and $\mu$. In any case I am totally confused.